# Gruel required to compile myblock

Tags: c++, cmake, gnuradio

So I was following the gnuradio tutorial on building an OOT. However i got into trouble with boost so i followed a solution that made me install boost and export by the command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BOOST_PREFIX/lib
```

I did that and got into another error after running cmake (below)

```
$cmake ../
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Boost version: 1.53.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
-- checking for module 'gruel'
--   package 'gruel' not found
-- Could NOT find GRUEL (missing:  GRUEL_LIBRARIES GRUEL_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- checking for module 'gnuradio-core'
--   package 'gnuradio-core' not found
-- Could NOT find GNURADIO_CORE (missing:  GNURADIO_CORE_LIBRARIES GNURADIO_CORE_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
-- checking for module 'cppunit'
--   package 'cppunit' not found
-- Could NOT find CPPUNIT (missing:  CPPUNIT_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:91 (message):
  Gruel required to compile newblock


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

please can any one help me solve this problem and add blocks to gnu radio

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the cppunit development headers; please install them.

The errors about Gruel indicate that you're trying to use a OOT template that was made for an older version of GNU Radio. Gruel was part of old versions of GNU Radio, and has been merged into other parts of GNU Radio, and is not available anymore.

The correct way of generating a module is using `gr_modtool`, which comes with GNU Radio, and automatically will only generate valid OOTs. This is rather nicely documented in the official [Guided Tutorials](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials), `gr_modtool nm my_module_name`, see Tutorial 3.

Best regards,
Marcus